# How to fetch a json object while using hooks in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying get my head around hooks in react, seemed pretty easy until I tried using fetch to get a json Object, the code I used is below

```
const [row, setRow] = useState({
    response: null,
    error: false,
    loading: true
});

    useEffect(() => {
        setRow({...row, error: null, loading: true});
        fetch("/todo?page[number]=1&page[size]=100000")
            .then(async (response) => {
                const data = await response.json();
                setRow({
                    response: data,
                    error: !response.ok,
                    loading: false,
                });
                console.log('response', data);
                console.log('Data fetched', row);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setRow({
                    response: {status: "network_failure"},
                    error: true,
                    loading: false,
                })
                console.log('err' + err);

            });
    }, []);
```

Which produces the following result:

[image]

If could give some hints I would be really be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you've mixed and matched synchronous and asynchronous programming in the same block, so lets simplify and just take the complete asynchronous approach using the `async`/`await` declarations. It immediately transformers your `useEffect` into this:

```
useEffect(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/todo?page[number]=1&page[size]=100000");
    const data = await response.json();
    setRow({
      response: data,
      error: !response.ok,
      loading: false
    });
  } catch (e) {
    setRow({
      response: { status: "network_failure" },
      error: true,
      loading: false
    });
    console.error(e);
  }
}, []);
```

As for your original question, it was fetching and returning the JSON as you requested, see the screenshot output. If you want to render the todo list, which is what I presume you want to do, change the `setState` to this:

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
const [error, setError] = useState(undefined);
```

Then we update the useEffect...

```js
useEffect(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("/todo?page[number]=1&page[size]=100000");
    const data = await response.json();
    setTodos(data);
    setLoading(false);
    setError(undefined);
  } catch (e) {
    setLoading(false);
    setError(e.message);
    setTodos([]);
  }
}, []);
```

Then we add rendering...

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  // ... useEffect & useState code
  if (error) {
    return (<p>There was an error loading todos, error: {error}</p>);
  }

  return (
    <div>{todos.map(todo => <p key={todo.id}>{todo.title}{todo.completed ? " (completed)" : ""})}</p></div>
  );
};
```

Working example on codepen using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com (it takes a while to load)

https://codepen.io/jmitchell38488/pen/GRoqeJp

Comment: Done thank you, for some reason when i try to console.log todos it doesn't show anything but when i render the results are there, once more thank you.

Comment: It won't be as yet. `useEffect` is an asynchronous hook, which will perform a task in the background and update the UI at a later date. You use `useState` to tell React to update the component with new data.